# split delimited column into new columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

need to split the delimited(~) column values into new columns dynamically. Thie input s a dataframe and column name list. We are trying to solve using spark datfarame functions. Please help.

```
Input:

|Raw_column_name|
|1~Ram~1000~US|
|2~john~2000~UK|
|3~Marry~7000~IND|

col_names=[id,names,sal,country]

output:
id | names | sal | country
1 | Ram | 1000 | US
2 | joh n| 2000 | UK
3 | Marry | 7000 | IND
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `split()` and then use the resulting array's elements to create columns.

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('raw_col_split_arr', func.split('raw_column_name', '~')). \
    select(func.col('raw_col_split_arr').getItem(0).alias('id'),
           func.col('raw_col_split_arr').getItem(1).alias('name'),
           func.col('raw_col_split_arr').getItem(2).alias('sal'),
           func.col('raw_col_split_arr').getItem(3).alias('country')
           ). \
    show()

# +---+-----+----+-------+
# | id| name| sal|country|
# +---+-----+----+-------+
# |  1|  Ram|1000|     US|
# |  2| john|2000|     UK|
# |  3|Marry|7000|    IND|
# +---+-----+----+-------+
```

In case the use case is extended to be a dynamic list of columns.

```
col_names = ['id', 'names', 'sal', 'country']

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('raw_col_split_arr', func.split('raw_column_name', '~')). \
    select(*[func.col('raw_col_split_arr').getItem(i).alias(k) for i, k in enumerate(col_names)]). \
    show()

# +---+-----+----+-------+
# | id|names| sal|country|
# +---+-----+----+-------+
# |  1|  Ram|1000|     US|
# |  2| john|2000|     UK|
# |  3|Marry|7000|    IND|
# +---+-----+----+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks @samkart. It exactly worked as I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is from_csv() function. The only thing that needs to be defined is schema which has the added advantage that data can be parsed to correct type automatically:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1~Ram~1000~US',), ('2~john~2000~UK',), ('3~Marry~7000~IND',)], ["Raw_column_name"])
df.show()

col_names = ['id', 'names', 'sal', 'country']
schema = ','.join([f'{name} string' for name in col_names])

# if custom type conversion is needed
# schema = "id int, names string, sal string, country string"

options = {'sep': '~'}
df2 = (df
       .select(from_csv(col('Raw_column_name'), schema, options).alias('cols'))
       .select(col('cols.*'))
       )
df2.printSchema()
df2.show()
```